# EmberJS: Application loading route and template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been trying to implement loading indication feature when my application bootstraps and begin to load data from server using `ember-data`. Created `templates/loading.hbs` template.

So far loading template is not being rendered while application starts, even tried to emulate network latency using `{latency: 4000}` option.

#### routes/application.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('items');
  }
});
```

#### templates/loading.hbs

```
<div class="loading-overlay">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

Library versions

```
ember-cli 0.0.39
ember 1.6.1
handlebars 1.3.0
ember-data 1.0.0-beta.8
```

Also thanks to `Balint Erdi` who has a great blog on frontend development with EmberJS http://balinterdi.com/2014/06/18/indicating-progress-loading-routes-in-ember-dot-js.html

#### Solution

Samples at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/
really helped.

```
App.LoadingView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'global-loading',
  elementId: 'global-loading'
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    loading: function() {
      var view = this.container.lookup('view:loading').append();
      this.router.one('didTransition', view, 'destroy');
    }
  }
});
```

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: You would also need a `LoadingRoute`. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/ or handle the `loading` action in the application route

Comment: You are closing your `div.spinner` with an `a` tag. Could also add your `spinner` and `loading-overlay` css to your question?

Comment: @Oliver I'm sorry it was a type, it is not about it.

Comment: That's the reason I asked for the CSS code

Comment: @JordyLangen thank you for your comment and link helped me. Would you please set it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would also need a `LoadingRoute` ([Loading and error substates](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates)) or handle the loading action in the application route